# JSpinner With Long (int64)

Tags: java, swing

so I'm using a JSpinner, but I really need the JSpinner to support longs (64-bit integers). I want to allow users to enter up to 50 trillion into the JSpinner and thus a long is a must.
Any and all help would be great. I've been looking for an answer but I can't seem to find one. I have tried declaring the JSpinner saying `JSpinner<long>` but to no avail.

My code looks like this: `JSpinner TheSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1000000000, 500, 50000000000000, 1000));`

Comment: JSpinner supports generics? That's a new one on me! Have you tried playing with the models? For instance perhaps create your own model based on the AbstractSpinnerModel. But don't just try and make up stuff that can never work such as `JSpinner<long>` (or even the more appropriate but still wrong `JSpinner<Long>`).

Comment: I have not. This is my first time using JSpinner and I'm fairly new to java. I can see if I can play with the models a little bit.
Thanks I'll take a look at the AbstractSpinnerModel.

Comment: What if you do, `new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1000000000L, 500L, 50000000000000L, 1000L));` Haven't tried it myself, but would make the numbers long literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding my comment,

> What if you do, new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1000000000L, 500L, 50000000000000L, 1000L)); Haven't tried it myself, but would make the numbers long literals.

Well heck, that seems to work:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class SpinnerTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1000000000L, 500L,
            50000000000000L, 1000L));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test it out shortly.

Comment: Just to be clear, this solution does appear to work as @SpencerGrantDoak desired it to.  However, it is actually using Doubles and not Longs.  If you look at the API, your choices are double, int, or Number.  The longs are cast to doubles in this example.  The important thing to note is that when you call `.getValue()`, the result will be a Double, not a Long. There may be other issues with doubles too, such as comparison.  This solution also works for me, but beware the limitations.

Comment: @Luke: indeed, you are correct. Many thanks for the correction!

Comment: You could update your answer. As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252736/jspinner-with-long-values/23254388#comment35584409_23254388), the `SpinnerNumberModel` *does* support `Long`, but if you use the primitve `long`, Java will call the double constructor instead, hence the `Double` return value. If you use the wrapper `Long`, everything works fine, and Java will choose the "generic" constructor.