# JSpinner with long values

Tags: java, long-integer, jspinner

I am in need of a JSpinner that can handle long, but JSpinner only handles double and int.  I did see an answer that used double to simulate a long, but I need to be able to exactly represent each value of long.  It is a program that works with each of the 64 bits, so double and int will not do.

Is it possible to have a JSpinner use BigInteger as the data type, or would I be better off just making designing my own JSpinner using a JPanel holding a JTextField and two JButtons specifically to handle my situation?  Right now, I'm leaning towards the latter.

Comment: Are you sure that [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) does not support `Long`? I also saw the comment in the other topic, but I can't find any hint of it in the documentation. Also take a look at the code, seems to be handling every data type just fine: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.java#SpinnerNumberModel.getStepSize%28%29

Comment: I'm very much a noob when it comes to Swing.  When using Oracle Java, the number range default was int and when I click on the max value returns the lowest negative value.  I'm not even sure how to make it use the other primitives as the number type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Aru mentioned, you can do it with the `SpinnerNumberModel`:

```
Long val = Long.MAX_VALUE;//set your own value, I used to check if it works
Long min = Long.MIN_VALUE;
Long max = Long.MAX_VALUE;
Long step = 1L;

SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(val, min, max, step);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
```

Note that you have to use `Long` as an object not a primitive `long`

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to answer. If you use the primitive long, the `SpinnerNumberModel(double value, double minimum, double maximum, double stepSize)` constructor will be called instead, hence it will only accept double values.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Works like a charm.  If I ever decide to publish this, you two will be mentioned!

Comment: I have ran into another JSpinner problem.  When I want it to use long values, it works like how I want.  It does a rollover when the extremes are reached.  I tried the same method for byte, but when it gets to 127, it just stops.  Should I override the getNextvalue and getPreviousValue methods to wrap around or is there a better idea.  I want to have a rollover JSpinner for byte, short, and int also.

Comment: It works only if you use the appropriate objects `Byte`,`Integer`,... because if you increase a `byte` with the value 127 it overflows to -128, but if you use the `Long` it doesn't overflow and it reached the max value. I think overriding the methods which you mentioned would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Dang it....  I thought I did it the same way you showed me, but I used byte (primitive) and not Byte (class).  When using the wrapper classes, it worked with the wrap around. (Wrapper....  Wrap around....  coincidence?)  When using primitives, it didn't.  Thanks again!